# Re render child components in svelte

Tags: components, render, svelte-3

i'm using svelte for my new project and pretty new to it. I have a parent component with multiple child components.
on child component allows me to select a date, and then i want to re render automatically all other child components using this date.
Actually, they won't rerender, unless i use a store, but is there another way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a two way binding by using `bind:`, but I think it should be used only in special cases. You can really mess a data flow with it. The store is usually much better choice. Anyway here is the code:

```
<script>
  import Child1 from "./Child1.svelte"
  import Child2 from "./Child2.svelte"
  let info = 'Hello from main';
</script>
​<h1>Main</h1>
<Child1 bind:text={info}></Child1>
<Child2 msg={info}></Child2>
```

Working example:
https://svelte.dev/repl/51daf11dcf3a4ade9b3ed525eec51967?version=3.24.1

There is also other ways to do this, for example: `createEventDispatcher`

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I was not sure this way worked, this is what i did (with one way binding and dispatch)... but the mistake was actually not here.
With the date changed, i wanted to call the story automatically and filter on it, but i forgot to use the $: to make the change (i use const unsubscribe = ...  instead of $: unsubscribe = ...).